# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) but only on device since upgrading to Xcode 5.1b4 with IOS7.1b4

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a segmented control I wrote myself (UISegmenterControl) which sends a message once the selected segment has changed:

```
- (void)setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)selectedSegmentIndex
{
    if(_selectedSegmentIndex != selectedSegmentIndex) {
        NSInteger segmentIndex = 0;

        for (UISegmenterControlSegment *segmentButton in self.segmentButtons) {
            if (segmentIndex == selectedSegmentIndex) {
                [segmentButton setSelected:YES];

                _selectedSegmentIndex = selectedSegmentIndex;

                if (self.target != nil) {
                    if ([self.target respondsToSelector:self.action]) {
                        objc_msgSend(self.target, self.action, self);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                [segmentButton setSelected:NO];
            }

            segmentIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

The objc_msgSend fires off (void)didChangeSegmentControl:(UISegmenterControl *)control in my view controller whilst passing a pointer to the segmented control itself.

Problem is, since upgrading to XCode 5.1 beta 4 and my development device to IOS 7.1 beta 4 my code is falling over on the device with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) when didChangeSegmentControl fires off.

It seems that the pointer to the segmented control (i.e. the 'control' parameter) is being lost between the objc_msgSend and didChangeSegmentControl.

What's confusing me most here is that this wasn't happening until I upgraded and still doesn't happen either on the simulator or on my device when profiling the app. I guess what I'm asking is: does this look to be a problem with my code (that somehow functioned perfectly fine on previous IOSes and/ or XCodes) or might this be an issue with the latest beta?

Please let me know if you need any more information about my app.

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? Without the full, symbolicated crash log it will be difficult to help. And, as you mention, both software versions are beta.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. The error occurs on... - (void)didChangeSegmentControl:(UISegmenterControl *)control in my view controller where 'control' appears as Nil.

Comment: Can you use `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:self.action withObject:self.target waitUntilDone:YES];` instead (I hope I have the object correct - please check)? And are you *absolutely* sure that the parameters in the `objc_msgSend` are non-nil?

Comment: Well, I had to rejig it a little- I assume you meant to type [self.target performSelectorOnMainThread:self.action withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES]; but yes- that's done it. Thanks a million- now to go off and read up on why that worked better than my approach :)

Comment: P.S. I'd absolutely love to give you the rep points for pointing me in the right direction here but I can't see any option to do that :(

Comment: I will post an answer - up to you if you accept it or not.

Comment: Do not start the name of your own class with the letters `UI`.

Comment: Re: beginning a class with UI. On it now thanks. Is this simply so self-made classes do not get confused with core classes or is there more to it than that?

Comment: Violates Apple NDA on unreleased products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `objc_msgSend`, can you use the following instead:

`[self.target performSelectorOnMainThread:self.action withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];`

P.S. Thanks for the update on the correct objects in the comments

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, I see objc_msgSend is quite a low-level function that doesn't manage threading for you as the performSelectorOnMainThread method would. Will steer away from using the former in the future.